# El cálculo de la media geométrica me devuelve; Media geométrica: inf

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

El código siguiente pretende calcular la media geométrica, cuando los valores de una variable se encuentran agrupados en intervalos de clase. La expresión utilizada para calcular la media geométrica es la que muestro a continuación, pero teniendo en cuenta que la Xi representa a las marcas de clase.

`$$\sigma = \widetilde {x}_g = \sqrt[N]{x_1^{f_1} * x_2^{f_2} *...* x_n^{fn}}$$`

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Marca_Clase': {
        pd.Interval(50.0, 57.0, closed='left'): 53.5,
        pd.Interval(57.0, 64.0, closed='left'): 60.5,
        pd.Interval(64.0, 71.0, closed='left'): 67.5,
        pd.Interval(71.0, 78.0, closed='left'): 74.5,
        pd.Interval(78.0, 85.0, closed='left'): 81.5,
        pd.Interval(85.0, 92.0, closed='left'): 88.5,
        pd.Interval(92.0, 99.0, closed='left'): 95.5
    },
    'Freq_Abs(f)': {
        pd.Interval(50.0, 57.0, closed='left'): 277,
        pd.Interval(57.0, 64.0, closed='left'): 282,
        pd.Interval(64.0, 71.0, closed='left'): 262,
        pd.Interval(71.0, 78.0, closed='left'): 312,
        pd.Interval(78.0, 85.0, closed='left'): 318,
        pd.Interval(85.0, 92.0, closed='left'): 283,
        pd.Interval(92.0, 99.0, closed='left'): 285
    },
    'Freq_Abs_Acum(F)': {
        pd.Interval(50.0, 57.0, closed='left'): 277,
        pd.Interval(57.0, 64.0, closed='left'): 559,
        pd.Interval(64.0, 71.0, closed='left'): 821,
        pd.Interval(71.0, 78.0, closed='left'): 1133,
        pd.Interval(78.0, 85.0, closed='left'): 1451,
        pd.Interval(85.0, 92.0, closed='left'): 1734,
        pd.Interval(92.0, 99.0, closed='left'): 2019
    },
    'Freq_Rel(fr)': {
        pd.Interval(50.0, 57.0, closed='left'): 0.13719663199603765,
        pd.Interval(57.0, 64.0, closed='left'): 0.13967310549777118,
        pd.Interval(64.0, 71.0, closed='left'): 0.12976721149083706,
        pd.Interval(71.0, 78.0, closed='left'): 0.15453194650817237,
        pd.Interval(78.0, 85.0, closed='left'): 0.1575037147102526,
        pd.Interval(85.0, 92.0, closed='left'): 0.14016840019811788,
        pd.Interval(92.0, 99.0, closed='left'): 0.1411589895988113
    },
    'Frec_Rel_Acum(Fr)': {
        pd.Interval(50.0, 57.0, closed='left'): 0.13719663199603765,
        pd.Interval(57.0, 64.0, closed='left'): 0.27686973749380883,
        pd.Interval(64.0, 71.0, closed='left'): 0.40663694898464586,
        pd.Interval(71.0, 78.0, closed='left'): 0.5611688954928182,
        pd.Interval(78.0, 85.0, closed='left'): 0.7186726102030708,
        pd.Interval(85.0, 92.0, closed='left'): 0.8588410104011888,
        pd.Interval(92.0, 99.0, closed='left'): 1.0
    }
}

df_intervalos = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Calcular la media geométrica
media_geometrica = (math.prod(df_intervalos['Marca_Clase'] ** df_intervalos['Freq_Abs(f)']) ** (1 /
                                                                            sum(df_intervalos['Freq_Abs(f)'])))
# Imprimir el resultado
print(f"Media geométrica: {media_geometrica}")
```

Me devuelve: Media geométrica: inf

Dado que no hay ningún cero en la columna Freq_Abs(f), ¿Cuál puede ser la causa de este error?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que es mas un tema de numeros grandes. Especificamente en la linea

`math.prod(df_intervalos['Marca_Clase'] ** df_intervalos['Freq_Abs(f)'])`

Por ejemplo, tratando de hacer el primer valor

`53.5 ** 277`

Arroja el error

`OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')`

Espero sea de ayuda